# Kак работает ternary conditional в Java?

Tags: java

Что делает эта функция "(fuelLevel > 0) ? 'Y' : 'N';"?

```
public class Ternary {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int fuelLevel = 3;

    char canDrive = (fuelLevel > 0) ? 'Y' : 'N';
    System.out.println(canDrive);

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Тенрарная запись вроде везде одинаковая. Это сокращенный вариант `if(){} else{}`. В вашем случае, если топлива больше 0, то машина может ехать, а иначе никак.

Answer (score 0):

```
(условие) ? (действие, которое произойдет, если условие выполняется) : (действие, которое произойдет, если условие не выполняется)
```

Comment: Не "действие, которое произойдет", а значение, которое будет вычислено